# Making a function for updating the moves of a 2-D array tic-tac-toe table

Tags: c, function, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have two functions for getting the user to make a move and the computer to generate moves, so when creating a function for updating the computer and user's moves, the 'x' and 'o' for the moves and '_' for a blank space, would I use pointers for my multidimensional array and if so how would you code that? An example with an explanation would very much be appreciated!

Comment: A [mcve] would be very much be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating a two-dimensional char array with a function, passing the *pointer* to the array as a parameter:

```
int main(){
    char array[5][5];
    updateArray(array, 0, 0, 'a');
}

void updateArray(char * arr, int row, int col, char c){
    arr[row][col] = c;
}
```

Note that when declaring an array in C, the array identifier (`array` in this case) is a pointer to the first element of the array. The brackets (`[row][col]`) access the elements of the array by calculating its address using *pointer arithmetic*. Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly do you intend to use pointers?  Pointers to what?  I don't think you need pointers at all, unless you have something specific in mind that isn't stated in your question.  I would use a simple two-dimensional array of chars.

Define your array like this:

```
char a[3][3] = {  
   {"_", "_", "_"},
   {"_", "_", "_"},
   {"_", "_", "_"}};
```

Your board might look like this: [4x4 multidimensional array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/It10S.jpg)

For example, to fill an "x" into the upper left-hand corner, write:

```
a[0][0] = 'x';
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Such a blödsinn!

Comment: What's a blödsinn?

Comment: Why?  I'm trying to help this guy.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a pointer to your functions, you could declare and use it like this:

```
computer_move(char (*p)[3][3])
{
    p[1][1] = 'x';
}

char ttt[3][3];
computer_move(&ttt);
```